# “Object doesn't support this property or method” Error when calling method inside function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using the chosen.js library. I have several dropdown-lists which are disabled and want them to be usable when a function is called.

```
<script>
...
    $('.chzn-select').each(function () {
        $(this).chosen();
    });

    function edit()
    {
        $('.chzn-select').each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
            $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
        });
    }
...
</script>
```

However, even when the edit() function is called, the dropdown-lists are not changed since the "chosen:updated" event is not triggered. When I add something like $(this).chosen("destroy") to the edit function I get the “Object doesn't support this property or method” error. This makes me think that the function is not able to use the chosen.js library? Also, the code works when it's not in a function:

```
<script>
...
    $('.chzn-select').each(function () {
        $(this).chosen();
    });

    $('.chzn-select').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
...
</script>
```

**Edit**
Sample snippet - needs updating

```js
$(".chzn-select").chosen();

// No need to loop to activate chosen
//$('.chzn-select').each(function () {
//    $(this).chosen();
//});

function edit()
{
    $('.chzn-select').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
}

$("#btn").click(()=>edit());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" />

<select class='chzn-select' disabled>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>

<select class='chzn-select' disabled>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>

<button type='button' id='btn'>enable</button>
```

Comment: Hi Tommy, it's likely that because of function hoisting that its referencing the old jquery object on the dom element. You can test this by moving the first each into the function itself and see if it works.

Comment: This would happen if 2nd jquery.js is being loaded.  At the top level (outside the function) add `console.log("outer", $.fn.jquery)` and inside the edit() function add `console.log("edit", jQuery.fn.jquery)` - then let us know the output of the two console logs.  But also look for a 2nd jquery `script` tag later in the page (as you're not using doc.ready).   If neither of those helps, please create a working snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) which *demonstrates* the issue.

Comment: the outer log says 3.3.1 and the edit log says 1.12.4, so a 2nd jquery.js is being loaded?

Comment: Yep - and 2nd jquery is overwritting your `chosen` which is attached to the first jquery.  Are you using a framework like asp.net-mvc or wordpress?  They sometimes add extra entries.

Comment: Yes I am using mvc. I'm not sure exactly where the second jquery.js is loaded. I noticed there were multiple jquery.js files with different files in my /Scripts/ folder. When I removed them the code works. All of the pages share a HeaderSection.cshtml which I think it might be loaded from. Thanks for your help.